# lighting and rendering

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, lighting

I was rendering out some cgi pictures for my mechanical keyboard when I hit the problem.

I used cycles with 200 samples to render it out. Some how in the middle of the picture there was a circular light shadow.

The more I increases the light power, the more brighter it is. Also, I would need some suggestions about making anodised aluminium material in blender. Mine is dull and unrealistic. When I switchs to material view, in camera view, the shading looks like this, and when I escapes the camera view, it turns back to norma.

How could I fix that?

[image]

https://www.mediafire.com/file/z2k3ch68k0eihsq/untitled123456.blend/file

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/XJccpNT. Here is my screenshots.

Comment: Use the edit option under your question and add the image there. Also can you provide the file? Use blend-exchange.com for that

Comment: You probably have to upload them one by one. But it's ok. Can you share the file? The problem is probably because of the way the lights are positioned. But will have to look at it to tell you what it is exactly

Comment: I work on a potato. It wans't able to handle the scene. So basically I won't be able to help. But in the time in which I was able to do things with your file, my best guess for now is that it's the biggest light. It's almost parallel to the camera and so it will show in the reflection on the plane. Best what I can suggest is try switching every light one by one and check. If it doesn't work plz wait for someone else to answer.

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.